# Libgdx gameover doesn't run new screen?

Tags: libgdx

I made my first game and when main actor get hit dies and gameover screen show's up.

My startup class

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

MenuScreen menuScreen;
GameScreen gameScreen;
GameOver gameOverScreen;


@Override
public void create() {
    menuScreen = new MenuScreen(this);
    gameScreen = new GameScreen();
    gameOverScreen = new GameOver(this);
    AssetsLoader.load();
    setScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    AssetsLoader.dispose();
}
```

MenuScreen.class

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen {

private GameState currentState;

Skin skin;
Stage stage;
SpriteBatch batch;

Game g;
public MenuScreen(Game g){
    create();
    this.g=g;
}
...
textButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            //System.out.println("Clicked! Is checked: " + button.isChecked());
            textButton.setText("Starting new game");
            g.setScreen( new GameScreen());

        }
    });
```

GameScreen.class

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private GameWorld world;
private GameRenderer renderer;
private float runTime;
MyGdxGame game;



public GameScreen(){
    game = new MyGdxGame();
    float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float gameWidth = 600;
    float gameHeight = screenHeight / (screenWidth / gameWidth);

    int midPointY = (int) (gameHeight / 2);
    int midPointX = (int) (gameWidth /2);

    world = new GameWorld();
    renderer = new GameRenderer(world, (int) gameHeight, midPointY);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(world.getNinja()));


}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    runTime += delta;
    world.update(delta);
    renderer.render(runTime);
    if(world.ninjaDead == true){
        game.setScreen(new GameOver(game));
...
```

and GameOver.class

```
public class GameOver implements Screen{
private GameState currentState;

Skin skin;
Stage stage;
SpriteBatch batch;
MyGdxGame game;

int scores;
public GameOver(MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
     create();
Gdx.app.log("startGameOver", "");
....
public void render (float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
    stage.draw();
    //   Table.drawDebug(stage);
}
```

Basically GameOver class is starting because log show "startGameOver" but screen show my game (GameScreen) moving only inputs stop working. I thing i shout stop rendering GameScreen, clear screen but i can't find out how?

Comment: I suggest that you should change your constructor for GameScreen into `public GameScreen(MyGdxGame game) {this.game = game;   ...}`.

Comment: why do you create a `new GameOver()` when you have one in your `MyGdxGame` class?

Comment: Without new GameOver() i get NPE. Fish good advise in every screen i should give in constructor MyGDXGame. Now sims to work fine.